# jak no longer available as it seems, create kml with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, kml

I need to create a KML file with JAXB.

But as it seems the library from http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home isnt available anymore? At least i am not able to load the page.

So how can i create a KML file with JAXB then!?

Comment: The website is back up and running. The code now lives on GitHub https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml

Answer (score 4):

The public website for Java API for KML (JAK) is here:
http://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/

The JAK discussion group (which includes some coding examples) is here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/javaapiforkml

The documentation as you noted can be found at: http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home

but at the time of this posting the website was down.

UPDATE: the JAK website is back online.

Comment: Yes.. but there is no documentation on how to use it?

Comment: You can still download the source code and API docs from the google code project but no examples except those found in the discussion forum.